Konishi operator anomalous dimension
The Konishi operators are operators in the ${\cal N}=4$ SYM theory and are given by:
$$ K = \sum _{i=1}^6Tr\ (\phi^i\phi^i) $$
The 2 point function of this operator is:
$$ \big\langle K(x)K(y)\big\rangle = \frac{1}{|x-y|^4}.$$
Therefore the conformal dimension is $\Delta=2$. To compute anomalous dimension perturbativaly one can compute the two loop, and the computation gives:
$$ \int\frac{d^4z}{|x-z|^4|z-y|^4} $$
from which one extract the anomalous dimenions. I know the result of this integral is $$\frac{1}{|x-y|^4}\log(\Lambda|x-y|),$$ where $\Lambda$ is the cutoff. However, I don't know how to obtain this result. How can we do this integral?

Very marginal: Is that Konishi Prof Ken-ichi Konishi? He was my master supervisor!

Hi BVquantization. Is this from a reference? Which page?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kZ_nXLhUx8&t=631s
